# Creating a flex chat and video server

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, red5

Hi guys i am trying to create a simple chat server. I have installed red5 server i need to know do i have to make a red5 server myself or all i have to do is connect flex with my red5 server and if so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you intend to create a chat application written in Flex that should use Red5 server behind. If yes, take a look on [this](http://tharas.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/chat-application-with-red5-and-flex/) article.